# How do I make a single blog like page that only certain users can post too, but all users have the ability to see it?

Tags: php, html, blogs

I'm currently a college student and I've been working on a project for a class and I've ran into an issue.
My project is a web page, coded in HTML and PHP, that is designed to be used in a business for manager to manage their employees tasks. My interest right now is to design a blog like system on the index page that only authorized users can post too but any user can read. I currently have log in system in place using PHP and that works great. But my problem is, I can't seem to figure out the blog like system in both my code using PHP and HTML to make that work with the database. One of my other issues is to how to make the webpage able to be posted too without coding each and every post. I'm new to PHP and it is confusing the heck out of me. 
Any help is much appreciated!

I have created a database in MyPHPAdmin called user_post with columns   user_id,user_post,and post_time. 
I have done some research and found to input the code on the submit button as follows, but this does not make sense.

```
$sql=mysql_query("insert into 
`user_post`(`user_id`,`user_post`,`post_time`,`post_status`)
 values('".$_SESSION['user_id']."','".$_POST['post']."',now(),1)"
);
```

Comment: If I got it right, you are asking 2 different questions **1-** how to keep unauthorized people from posting **2-** how to show the posts on the page automatically without writing every post ? If this is the case I suggest posting another question to keep this question focused on the first problem, this could encourage better answers.

Comment: Don’t try to solve several things at once. Before you worry about logins and conditional views, first learn to submit a form and update the database.  To start with, you’re using a command that has been deprecated for some time. Go to phpdelusion.com and learn the right way, with pdo. Once you get that under your belt, you can tackle some of these other issues.